# RuntimeError: abort([object Object]). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hd-wallets

I saw a similar question but does not solve my issue. here is my contract code based on my research.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <=0.8.4;

contract Lottery {
    // address payable is the same as address, but have transfer and send members.
    address payable public manager;
    address payable[]  public players;
    
    constructor (){
        // msg.sender is an address where the current function call came from
        manager = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function enter() public payable {
        //  msg.value is the amount of wei sent with the message to the contract
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }
    
    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp)));

    }
    
    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        // transfer reverts on failure
        players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
        // resets the array
        players = new address payable[](0);
    }
    
    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }
    
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory ) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

this is the error:

```
RuntimeError: abort([object Object]). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at process.abort (/home/projects/ethereum/lottery/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:13012)
```

I checked "solc/soljson" first letter was "null".

I checked solc github repo and there is a similar issue but still open: https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js/issues/493

compiling and testing this work is working. but the issue is with deploying. here is the deploy.js

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { abi, evm } = require("./compile");
const config = require("./config");

const bytecode = evm.bytecode.object;
const abi_string = JSON.stringify(abi);

const metamask_mnemonic = config.metamask_mnemonic;

const ropsten_network = config.ropsten_network;
const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase: metamask_mnemonic,
  },
  providerOrUrl: ropsten_network,
});

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  console.log("Attempting to deploy from account", accounts[0]);

  const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi_string))
    .deploy({ data: "0x" + bytecode })
    .send({ gas: "1000000", from: accounts[0] });

  // this address is used in etherscan to find the account
  console.log("Contract deployed to" + result.options.address);
  // console.log("ABI:" + abi_string);
};
deploy();
```

this is abi_string:

```
abi_String [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"enter","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getPlayers","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable[]","name":"","type":"address[]"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"manager","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pickWinner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"players","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

this accounts[0]:

```
Attempting to deploy from account 0x3FB83280e44B4c1b77E8fb3ce6e0E1C271BE1659
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the deploy() in try/catch block:

```js
const deploy = async () => {
  try {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log("Attempting to deploy from account", accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi_string))
      .deploy({ data: "0x" + bytecode })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });

    // this address is used in etherscan to find the account
    console.log("Contract deployed to", result.options.address);
    console.log("ABI:" + abi_string);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

catch() block logged this error:

```
{ code: -32000, message: 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value' }
```

So I visit this faucet to transfer some ether to `accounts[0]`

https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Successfully deployed